# Telerik Html5 Report Viewer "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET' "

Tags: html, telerik, telerik-reporting

I am getting this while using html5 report viewer in my MVC project

Unable to get report parameters:
Report 'Application.Reports.Report1, WebAppUsingTelerikReport' cannot be resolved.

After clicking the error in console it says The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

My ReportsController

```
public class ReportsController : ReportsControllerBase
{
    protected override IReportResolver CreateReportResolver()
    {
        var appPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reports");
        //var reportsPath = Path.Combine(appPath, @"..\..\..\Report Designer\Examples");

        return new ReportFileResolver(appPath)
            .AddFallbackResolver(new ReportTypeResolver());
    }
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    protected override ICache CreateCache()
    {
        return Telerik.Reporting.Services.Engine.CacheFactory.CreateFileCache();
    }
}
```

View

```
@{
Layout = null;
var typeReportSource = new TypeReportSource() { TypeName = "Application.Reports.Report1, WebAppUsingTelerikReport" 
 };
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;


        $("#reportViewer1")
            .telerik_ReportViewer({
                serviceUrl: "/api/reports/",
                templateUrl: '../ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate-8.2.14.1027.html',
                reportSource: {
                    report: "@typeReportSource",
                },
                viewMode: telerikReportViewer.ViewModes.INTERACTIVE,
                scaleMode: telerikReportViewer.ScaleModes.FIT_PAGE_WIDTH,
                scale: 1.0,
                ready: function () {
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a resource is being requested which you have specified not to accept HTTP GET requests. I would expect based on your code that the HTML5 Report Viewer is attempting to call `CreateCache()` but you have specified it should only accept HTTP POST requests with `[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]`. If this isn't the issue check if there is another Controller method which is restricted from processing GET requests.

Using a debugger on the server side or in-browser network profiler on the client side it should be easy to identify which requested resource is causing the issue.